# Why SPARK cached RDD spill to disk?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have next code, where I am repartition filtered input data and persist it:

```scala
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
      .parquet(path)
      .as[struct1]
      .filter(dateRange(_,lowerBound,upperBound))
      .repartition(nrInputPartitions)
      .persist()

df.count
```

I expect all data to be stored in Memory, but instead I get the following in Spark UI:

> **Storage**
>
> ```
> Size in Memory   424.2 GB 
> Size on Disk     44.1 GB
> ```

Is it because some partition didn't have enough Memory, and Spark automatically switched to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark cache only keeps a fraction of RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502234/spark-cache-only-keeps-a-fraction-of-rdd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because some partition didn't have enough Memory, and Spark automatically switched to MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level?

Almost. It is because it is not `RDD`, but `Dataset`, and default storage level for `Datasets` is `MEMORY_AND_DISK`. Otherwise your suspicion is true - if there is not enough memory or cache eviction is required data goes to disk (but technically speaking it is not aspill).